# Using drawstyle "steps-mid" together with x-log-scale causes step points to be non-centered

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Matplotlib offers various options for the [drawstyle](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle). `steps-mid` does the following:

> The steps variants connect the points with step-like lines, i.e. horizontal lines with vertical steps. [...]
>   'steps-mid': The step is halfway between the points.

This works fine when the x-scale is linear however when using a log-scale it still seems to compute the step points by averaging in data-space rather than log-space. This leads to data points not being centered between the steps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(0, 10, num=10)
y = np.arange(x.size) % 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-mid', marker='s')
```

[image: Plot]

Is there a way to use step-like plotting together with x-log-scale such that the steps are centered between data points in log-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way other than building the steps correctly in log space yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(0, 10, num=10)
y = np.arange(x.size) % 2


def log_steps_mid(x, y, **kwargs):
    x_log = np.log10(x)
    x_log_mid = x_log[:-1] + np.diff(x_log)/2
    x_mid = 10 ** x_log_mid
    x_mid = np.hstack([x[0],
                       np.repeat(x_mid, 2),
                       x[-1]])
    y_mid = np.repeat(y, 2)
    ax.plot(x_mid, y_mid, **kwargs)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(x, y, ls='', marker='s', color='b')
log_steps_mid(x, y, color='b')
```

[image: Correct log steps-mid]

Comment: I was afraid this is the only option but it is somewhat annoying since I manually need to transform all data that I want to include in my plot.